# How can I spell check words ignoring optional hyphens?

Tags: browser, spell-check

I am using a RTE (TinyMce) for text creation in a browser. The RTE is inserting non-visible optional hyphens (code: '­' or '\u00ad') into words of a minimum length for hyphenation as the user writes.

The problem i got now is to find a spellchecker that is able to check my words even though they consist not only of letters but additionally of optional hyphens. I did only find spell checkers that i.e. checking the word "goldfish" looked at it as two words cause of the optional hyphen between "gold" and "fish".

Is there a spellchecker that is able to be modified in any way to ignore them? Is there a way to configure a spellchecker to ignore such soft-hyphens? (The solution does not need to be open-source.)

Adding words to a dictionary is not an option.

The solution should work for Safari or FireFox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to my problem, so i'll answer my own question.

Hunspell seems to ignore those soft-hyphens and works with FireFox.